# Android startActivityForResults and returning to calling applications on exceptions

Tags: android, android-intent, external, startactivityforresult

currently i have an application that is called from an external application
The flow is as followed:

External -> A -> B -> C -> External (With data)
this is done by retaining A and when C finishes, we return to A and call setResult and finish() in A.

This works fine for most of the use case except if there's a crash somewhere in the process.
So for example

External App -> A -> B -> C (CRASHES HERE)
It will return to B instead of going back to the external application. this is problematic for my use-case as it's an integrated environment without user interaction.

I have tried overwriting the DefaultExceptionHandler however have not had any luck in trying to get the correct flow. Is there a way to return to the calling application always on a crash?

Comment: What are A, B and C,? Images? Apps? Fragments?

Comment: @blackapps activities

Answer (score 0):

So far I found using activity.getCallingActivity()
and I am calling startActivity with this component. it appears to work.